# Sql server Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server Only First Time

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-connection

When I try to connect to sql server from console application I get the following error for the first time (every time). If I run the application again then this error is not there.

Below is the code I am using

```
        DataTable tblResults = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Common.DatabaseConnection))
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(tblResults);
            con.Close();
        }
```

The issue comes every time I run the application for the firsts time. IF I run the application again then the connection works.

Connection String

```
data source=sdfasdf.server.com;initial catalog=databasename;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=secret;
```

Comment: can you show your connectionstring please

Comment: Added the connection string